# Is MDX (analysis service) still relevant

Tags: mdx, in-memory-database, hana

Microsoft introduced MDX for analysis services and since then few things have changed in the market place.  Microsoft now have column store analysis services tabular and power pivot that run on DAX. Also database vendors have moved to in-memory (SAP Hana).  I have long given up on MDX as unnecessary in the current DAX tabular environment, however SAP HANA excel pug-in now uses MDX to query HANA models and I'm trying to access if its worth learning MDX again.

Thanks

Comment: I can write members such as "CurrentMonth"/"YTDtotal" in mdx - put them on the columns of a table - then put these measures on the rows "Revenue"/"NumUsers"/"NumPurchases" ...try doing that in DAX!

Comment: Saying that though if you're involved with the Microsoft stack better to learn DAX in detail.

Comment: @whytheq - there are functions in DAX for that sort of calculations. Saying that is not possible is not entirely true, although the syntax is a lot different.

Comment: @SouravA I've not seen this anywhere - or via any of the people I've asked (some of them MVP): do you have a reference please? (yes it is possible to create a measure "CurrentMonth_Revenue" but how do you create something like "YTDtotal" that is independent from Revenue or NumUsers?

Comment: Not sure what this question is doing on SO?! There are a lot of features not yet available in Tabular models. Plus, MDX will live as long as there are companies which can't afford requisite hardware. Tabular model thrives and lives entirely on the RAM, whereas Multidimensional models store data on disk(much much cheaper). I mean there are people still on Windows XP, for crying out loud. Not every one likes to change.

Comment: Can you put up a question on SO(with DAX tag)? Will give it a shot.

Comment: @SouravA as I said I've already asked an analysis services MVP - and it isn't practically possible - so I don't need to ask a question

Comment: You might be interested in this presentation (PPT slides or video): https://sqlbits.com/Sessions/Event9/MDX_and_DAX-compare_and_contrast

Comment: Good for you. But if you ask a question, there are chances people having similar question will bump into yours and would benefit them(your call). And BTW, there are a lot of things not possible in DAX(for e.g. computing percentles in the earlier version), but workarounds exist.

Answer (score 1):

Using MDX is one of several options to query SAP HANA information models.
Standard SQL queries would do just as well.

MDX is mainly aimed at providing a common interface language to access data sources and return the data into multi-dimensional structures.
It also provides several language concepts not covered by SQL, e.g. hierarchy processing.

I've yet to see a user that would write his MDX statements for ad-hoc reporting by hand...

Comment: Br I write ad hoc mdx "by hand" using MDX Studio - the code is then used in SQL server via this stored proc https://olapextensions.codeplex.com/ also we write our own mdx and feed it into reports on Pyramid i.e. bypass their wizards and write it up front.

Comment: to me it looks like once you have a good model MDX is a far better option than SQL. However if you are starting from scratch for a one off scenario, SQL can be easier

Answer (score 1):

I work for a company that has a very mature and precise `olap` environment - `MDX` is 100% relevent.

We will start to look to move certain functionality into the `Tabular/DAX` world but I wouldn't imagine stopping `MDX` for a good while.

To me it is a very pretty declarative language - elegant and powerful - much more so than `sql` or what I've so far seen of `DAX`.

If `sql` is checkers(draughts) then `mdx` is chess!